# Task.WaitAll() hangs in console application

Tags: c#, asynchronous

I have a console application in which I need to retrieve some data from 4 different sites.  I placed each HTTP request in a task and I wait for them all to complete.

It was working when I only had to get data from 2 sites. but then I needed to add other sources of data and when adding 3 or more requests, the Task.WaitAll() hangs.

Below is my code.

The reason I ended up using Task.WaitAll() was because I need to stop and prevent the console application from exiting - i.e. I need to perform other tasks only after all the HTTP requests come back with data.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        static Task[] tasks = new Task[3];

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            try
            {
                Run();
            }
            catch (System.Exception ex)
            {

            }
        }

        public static async void Run()
        {
            //works when using one or two tasks
            tasks[0] = HttpExtensions.GetMyData("http://www.w3.org/TR/PNG/iso_8859-1.txt"); 
            tasks[1] = HttpExtensions.GetMyData("http://www.w3.org/TR/PNG/iso_8859-1.txt");

            //fails when add 3 or more task
            tasks[2] = HttpExtensions.GetMyData("http://www.w3.org/TR/PNG/iso_8859-1.txt"); 
            //tasks[3] = HttpExtensions.GetMyData("http://www.w3.org/TR/PNG/iso_8859-1.txt"); 

            Task.WaitAll(tasks);

            var result4 = ((Task<Stream>)tasks[2]).Result;

        }
    }

    public static class HttpExtensions
    {
        public static Stopwatch sw;
        public static long http_ticks = 0;

        public static Task<HttpWebResponse> GetResponseAsync(this HttpWebRequest request)
        {
            var taskComplete = new TaskCompletionSource<HttpWebResponse>();
            request.BeginGetResponse(asyncResponse =>
            {
                try
                {
                    HttpWebRequest responseRequest = (HttpWebRequest)asyncResponse.AsyncState;
                    HttpWebResponse someResponse = (HttpWebResponse)responseRequest.EndGetResponse(asyncResponse);
                    taskComplete.TrySetResult(someResponse);
                }
                catch (WebException webExc)
                {
                    HttpWebResponse failedResponse = (HttpWebResponse)webExc.Response;
                    taskComplete.TrySetResult(failedResponse);
                }
            }, request);
            return taskComplete.Task;
        }


        public static async Task<Stream> GetMyData(string urlToCall)
        {

            HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(urlToCall);
            request.Method = HttpMethod.Get;
            HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)await request.GetResponseAsync();
            //using (var sr = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
            //{

            return response.GetResponseStream();
            //}
        }

    }

    public static class HttpMethod
    {
        public static string Head { get { return "HEAD"; } }
        public static string Post { get { return "POST"; } }
        public static string Put { get { return "PUT"; } }
        public static string Get { get { return "GET"; } }
        public static string Delete { get { return "DELETE"; } }
        public static string Trace { get { return "TRACE"; } }
        public static string Options { get { return "OPTIONS"; } }
        public static string Connect { get { return "CONNECT"; } }
        public static string Patch { get { return "PATCH"; } }
    }
}
```

Comment: `public static async void Run()` this is almost certainly your problem.  You should return `Task` instead of void.

Comment: see https://sachabarbs.wordpress.com/2014/02/04/awaitable-console-application/

Comment: @DavidL ok I read a bit about when to use void return type, however if I do return a Task, then I need to await Run() and make Main async?  I'm getting build error when I try.

Comment: @DavidL I'm thinking more about deadlock situation in the static methods of my http class.

Comment: That's largely caused by a poor implementation in the async/await world.  Please see my answer below.

Comment: Have a look at [this](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html) - it's probably the problem here.

Comment: Note: C# 7.1 adds support for Async Main methods: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-7-1

Answer (score 2):

There a number of concerns.

First, as I mentioned in the comments above, by not returning a `Task` you are more or less hanging your application since it can't tell when the Task is completed.

However, once you change the `Run()` method to return a task, you need to invoke it via a Task.Run call in your `Main` method.

Second, you are over-complicating your code by using WebClient.  Switch to HttpClient and take advantage of its natural async/await API.

Third, you aren't actually awaiting anything in your `Run()` method so changing it to a task does nothing since you aren't awaiting a result which will cause it to run synchronously (no pun intended).  Update your method to await a result.

Finally, `WaitAll` blocks the thread, which may not be what you want.  You can use `WhenAll` instead and await that call, allowing your application to release the thread while your tasks run.

Below is a complete, working example of my recommended modifications, simplified to show a working program.  The Main method recommendation is taken from https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/fe9acdfc-66cd-4b43-9460-a8053ca51885/using-new-asyncawait-in-console-app?forum=netfxbcl

```
class Program
{
    static Task[] tasks = new Task[3];
    static HttpClient _client = new HttpClient();

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Main start");
        Task t = Run();
        t.ContinueWith((str) =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine(str.Status.ToString());
            Console.WriteLine("Main end");
        });
        t.Wait();
    }

    public static async Task Run()
    {
        tasks[0] = GetMyData("http://www.w3.org/TR/PNG/iso_8859-1.txt");
        tasks[1] = GetMyData("http://www.w3.org/TR/PNG/iso_8859-1.txt");
        tasks[2] = GetMyData("http://www.w3.org/TR/PNG/iso_8859-1.txt");

        await Task.WhenAll(tasks);

        var result4 = (await (Task<Stream>)tasks[2]);
    }

    public static async Task<Stream> GetMyData(string urlToCall)
    {
        return await _client.GetStreamAsync(urlToCall);
    }
}
```

Comment: Is it safe to call `GetStreamAsync` and dispose of the `HttpClient` before the stream is fully read?

Comment: @ScottChamberlain whoops, my oversight, you're 100% correct, thank you.  Updated.

Comment: @DavidL I was not having luck with this - first I noticed with 4 http requests, the program hangs just like before.  When I reduced to 2 or less lasts, the program just exits without executing the items inside the ContinueWith().  I placed a Console.ReadKey() after the WriteLine("Main end") - should it have stopped there and waited for me to enter something on the keyboard?

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is more of understanding Task and async await; and I may be wrong so apologies up front.

Task is a managed thread that goes into a thread pool.  Task has a Task.Result of Type T.

You can create a Task and then Start it and then Wait it. (Never a good idea to start and then immediately wait a task but for understanding...)

```
var task = new Task(() => DoWork());
task.Start();
task.Wait();
```

The task will perform the DoWork() method in a new thread.
The calling thread will BLOCK at task.Wait();

You can also give a Task a ContinueWith Action that will perform the remaining work on the calling thread.

```
var task = new Task(() => DoWorkOnNewThread());
task.ContinueWith(() => MainThreadWork());
task.Start(); //Notice no more task.Wait();
```

So, if you're following that little bit then you can sort of use async await correctly.

The async keyword tells the compiler to wrap all remaing code AFTER reaching the await keyword WHERE A GetAwaiter() is returned.  This is important because until you actually create a task (preferably started also) and return it then you have no GetAwaiter();

```
private Task DoWorkAsync()
{
    var task = new Task(() => DoWork());
    task.Start();
    return task;
}

private async void Method()
{
     //Main thread code...
     await DoWorkAsync(); //Returns to whoever called Method()
     //More main thread code to be QUEUED to run AFTER DoWorkAsync is complete.
     //This portion of code, when compiled, is essentially wrapped in the ContinueWith(...
}
```

So if you're still following along then here's the kicker.  You're on the same thread UNTIL you return a GetAwaiter() which is only found in a Task.  If the Task has never started then you'll await that Task forever technically. So here's some comments showing the thread transitions.

```
private Task DoWorkAsync()
{
    Debug.WriteLine("Still on main thread")
    var task = new Task(() =>
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("On background thread");
    });
    task.Start(); //On main thread.
    return task; //On main thread.
}

private async void Method()
{
     Debug.WriteLine("On main thread");
     await DoWorkAsync(); //returns to caller after DoWorkAsync returns Task
     Debug.WriteLine("Back on main thread"); //Works here after the task DoWorkAsync returned is complete
}
```

An easier way to return the task running is to return Task.Run(() => DoWork()); If you look at the return value of Run it is Task and that task has already been started.

Forgive me if this isn't what you wanted but I felt like there is more of a confusion about using async await correctly than there is confusion about your code.  I may be wrong but I felt that if you could understand more about the Task itself and how async await works you would see your issue.  If this isn't what you're looking for I'll delete the answer.

Comment: Hi thanks for taking the time to answer, I noticed it was downvoted, but not by me.  Yes I have some async/await confusion and the information you posted is good to read.  However do you have any idea why my scenario hangs only when adding 3 or more tasks, but not with 2 tasks?  I'm still not too clear about it because I'm still inside Run() method when it happens and each of my tasks inside Run all return a Task<T>